# How to cache a single csv file into a KTable in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a situation that we have to cache and persist a CSV file in a Kafka KTable. Is it possible in Kafka?
According to what I have researched, we can read a CSV file in KTable but it won't be persisted (I might be wrong here). I have not been able to find anything related to it in the docs.

To be a little specific:

- We need to take a CSV file.
- Send it to a KTable and cache/persist it as it is.

One more thing: if it's possible, will it read the file line by line or the whole file can be sent too with a single key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, yes, although, I'm not sure I understand why you wouldn't just load the CSV itself within the application as a list of rows.

> will it read the file line by line or the whole file can be sent too with a single key?

Depends how you read the file. And you'd first produce the data to Kafka. A KTable must consume from a topic, not files

Note: Kafka has a max message default size at 1MB, and is not meant for file transfer

> it won't be persisted

I'm not sure where you read that. You can persist the data in a compacted topic, although, you'd want to then have some key for each row of the file